# Does log-rank statistic converge in distribution to a beta distribution or Pearson I distribution?

Tags: convergence, beta-distribution, logrank-test

> The logrank test statistic compares estimates of the hazard functions of the two groups at each observed event time. It is constructed by computing the observed and expected number of events in one of the groups at each observed event time and then adding these to obtain an overall summary across all-time points where there is an event.

> Consider two groups of patients, e.g., treatment vs. control. Let $1, \ldots, J$ be the distinct times of observed events in either group. Let $N_{1, j}$ and $N_{2, j}$ be the number of subjects "at risk" (who have not yet had an event or been censored) at the start of period $j$ in the groups, respectively. Let $O_{1, j}$ and $O_{2, j}$ be the observed number of events in the groups at time $j$. Finally, define $N_{j}=N_{1, j}+N_{2, j}$ and $O_{j}=O_{1, j}+O_{2, j}$.

> The null hypothesis is that the two groups have identical hazard functions, $H_{0}: h_{1}(t)=h_{2}(t)$. Hence, under $H_{0}$, for each group $i=1,2, O_{i, j}$ follows a hypergeometric distribution with parameters $N_{j}, N_{i, j}, O_{j}$. This distribution has expected value $E_{i, j}=N_{i, j} \frac{O_{j}}{N_{j}}$ and variance $V_{i, j}=E_{i, j}\left(\frac{N_{j}-O_{j}}{N_{j}}\right)\left(\frac{N_{j}-N_{i, j}}{N_{j}-1}\right)$.
> For all $j=1, \ldots, J$, the logrank statistic compares $O_{i, j}$ to its expectation $E_{i, j}$ under $H_{0}$. It is defined as
> $$
> Z=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{J}\left(O_{i, j}-E_{i, j}\right)}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{J} V_{i, j}}} \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{N}(0,1) \quad(\text { for } i=1 \text { or } 2 \text { ) }
> $$

> By the central limit theorem, the distribution of $Z$ converges to that of a standard normal distribution as $J$ approaches infinity and therefore can be approximated by the standard normal distribution for a sufficiently large $J$. An improved approximation can be obtained by equating this quantity to Pearson type I or II (beta) distributions with matching first four moments, as described in Appendix B of the Peto and Peto paper. ${ }^{[2]}$

Peto, Richard; Peto, Julian (1972). "Asymptotically Efficient Rank Invariant Test Procedures". Journal of the Royal Statistical Society, Series A. Blackwell Publishing. 135 (2): 185–207. doi:10.2307/2344317. hdl:10338.dmlcz/103602. JSTOR 2344317.
does not give a proof of converging to beta distribution.

Is there a proof that log-rank statistic converges to a beta/pearson I distribution?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logrank_test

Comment: I don't see a claim that it converges to a (standardized) beta distribution there. A suitable sequence of standardized betas will converge to a standard normal, naturally (so in that sense it will 'work' asymptotically), but the claim is about better approximation in finite samples; this is simply matching moments; the four-parameter beta has two additional degrees of freedom over the normal, which allows it to approximate distributions that are skewed or have some kinds of kurtosis different from the normal. ... ctd

Comment: ctd.. With two additional degrees of freedom plus the ability to get as close as desired to the normal, we should not be surprised that it manages to fit better in finite samples.